# How do I install this type of door-bottom weatherstrip?

Tags: doors, exterior, weatherstripping

I had a local shop (now closed since the owners retired) hang some door slabs for me and they included a weatherstrip with each door that looks like this:

[image: door bottom weatherstrip]

They left them off presumably because the doors were unfinished, but now that they're finished and installed I'd like to seal up the bottom of the doors.

What's the preferred way of installing these? Adhesive? Screws? Staples? And if I do use fasteners, where should they be? Note that the little flaps appear to be too close together to fit up the sides of an exterior door.

Or should I purchase a different kind of weatherstrip from somewhere else? The thresholds on the door frames are adjustable in height so I have some wiggle room.

Comment: What does the bottom of the door look like? Did they just hang slabs or replace entire doors? Are the thresholds adjustable? The answer depends on the situation.

Comment: @isherwood thresholds are adjustable, and they were complete pre-hung units that I purchased and installed. The bottom of the door is just a plan flat rectangle like the other three edges.

Comment: They were probably just stapled on at the factory. Do you see any holes? The folded flanges at the sides act as a seal against the door bottom.

Comment: Isherwood is correct about they are stapled on. Usually a line of caulk is applied at the bottom of the door first, on all occasions I have seen and it is stapled between the bulbs and the flipper seal. There is no reason why you could not pilot and countersink the plastic and use small gauge flat head screws either. If you go that route, make sure the screws are about 1" from the end. You may want to consider angling screws into the space created by the round parts of the weather stripping. The more secure you can set the ends, the more durable the mounting will be....